# OData string error and problem with date formats

Tags: filter, connection, odata

I try to get data to excel with OData. When I use link below it works fine:
http://xts/odata/AuditAggregationOdata
or 
http://xts/odata/AuditAggregationOdata/?$filter=(ObjectId%20eq%2041143%20)

But when I try to use some date range or funcion with date it does not work. I try to write everything but without right result:

1.
http://xts/odata/AuditAggregationOdata/?$filter=year(FirstRead)%20eq%202016

Error message:
Unable to connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect
Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed: 
OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.)
OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (Internal Server Error)
OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.)"

Or this one

2.
http://xts/odata/AuditAggregationOdata/?$filter=(FirstRead%20gt%20datetime%272019-01-01T00:00:00Z%27%20and%20FirstRead%20lt%20datetime%272019-01-03T00:00:00Z%27)

Error message:
Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed: 
OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.DateTime' for operator kind 'GreaterThan'.)
OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. (Internal Server Error)
OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.DateTime' for operator kind 'GreaterThan'.)"

Note:
Property Name="FirstRead" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an internal server error.

When I tried different entity but with same conditions, it worked fine. I put the right solution below:

```
http://xts/odata/ProfileData(path='Odata_test%7Codata_test')?$filter=year(From)%20eq%202019

http://xts/odata/ProfileData(path='Odata_test%7Codata_test')?$filter=From%20ge%20datetimeoffset%272016-01-01%27%20and%20From%20lt%20datetimeoffset%272020-01-01%27
```